# Best way to modify html form elements with php?

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, xpath

How do I modify and insert form elements using PHP?

I have a form assigned to a variable in PHP like so:

```
$the_original_form = '
<form method="post" action="whatever.php">
<input type="text" name="iamtextfield" id="textisme">
<input type="file" name="iamfilefield" id="fileisme">
<input type="hidden" name="hideme" value="nope">
</form>
';
```

I have a second variable:

```
$put_me_on_the_top = '<div class="getinme">';
```

And a third variable:

```
$put_me_on_the_bottom = '</div><div class="justsomethingelse">hi there</div>';
```

And a modified form element of:

```
$i_have_changed = '<input type="file" name="filepartdeux" id="iamabetterfile">';
```

And I want to end up with:

```
$the_modified_form = '
<form method="post" action="whatever.php">
<input type="text" name="iamtextfield" id="textisme">
<div class="getinme">
    <input type="file" name="filepartdeux" id="iamabetterfile">
</div>
<div class="justsomethingelse">hi there</div>
<input type="hidden" name="hideme" value="nope">
</form>
';
```

Comment: Use [**DOM**](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: Your question is not clear: it sounds like you try to use PHP (server-side) to modify the client-side (something you should do with Javascript/jQuery).

Comment: I really didn't want the client modifying my form. I'd prefer to do it server side. But I'm not sure if I would be best using php dom, xpath, or regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a mal-formed or well formed HTML document into a new [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and manipulate it as you would XML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($the_original_form);

// You can manipulate using the DOM object just follow the PHP manual for usage
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $element)
{
    // Evaluate elements here and insert / extract / delete as necessary
}
```

- Malformed HTML will throw errors from DOMDocument, you will need methods to deal with those errors. Try and use well formed HTML as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Check [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) - a jQuery port to PHP. It's very simple tool to work with HTML in PHP and it's especially suited for ones with basic jQuery knowledge.